# Audio data set of (telephone) conversations and their transcriptions

Tags: machine-learning, language, corpora, audio

I need records of telephone conversations (or simple conversations between two persons) with their transcripts. I need English and French datasets.

Comment: big brother, is that you?

Comment: Have you had any luck with this?

Answer (score 3):

Most telephone recording datasets are privately owned by parties who have access to such data like for example call-centers and tech-support companies etc. This data is subject to various ***privacy laws*** (which differ from one country to another), therefore it is tricky to find such data.

Nevertheless, the [CallHome database](https://ca.talkbank.org/access/CallHome) and the [CallFriend database](https://ca.talkbank.org/access/CallFriend) -by [TalkBank](https://ca.talkbank.org/)- seem to fit your requirements. Furthermore, [TalkBank](https://ca.talkbank.org/) provides a variety of datasets with support for different languages. The full list can be found [here](https://ca.talkbank.org/access/).

Please mind the licenses of these datasets and the [TalkBank Ground Rules](https://talkbank.org/share/). 
The TalkBank data is subject to the [CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/).